# JS class method type error when calling in constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, typeerror

Here is the snippet code scenario.

The same type error is given:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.createHeader is not a function"

```js
class HtmlElement {
 
 constructor(container, tag, id, classes, text){
  let html = document.createElement(tag);
  classes.split(' ').forEach(cls => html.classList.add(cls));
  if(text) html.innerText = text;
  html.id = id;
  container.appendChild(html);
  return html;
 }
}

class HtmlTable extends HtmlElement {

 constructor(container, id, classes, arrayWithObjects){
  super(container, 'table', id, classes);
  
  this.arrayWithObjects = arrayWithObjects;
  this.columns = Object.keys(this.arrayWithObjects);
  
  if(this.columns.length > 0) this.createHeader(this.columns);
  if(this.arrayWithObjects && this.arrayWithObjects.length > 0 ) this.createDataRows(this.arrayWithObjects);
  
  
 }
 
 createHeader(columns){
  console.log(columns);
 }
 
 createDataRows(arrayWithObjects){
  console.log(arrayWithObjects);
 }
 
 getDataObjects(){
  let headers = table.querySelectorAll('thead th');
  let dataRows = this.table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
  var all = [];
  
  dataRows.forEach( row => {
   let cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
   var obj = {};
   cells.forEach( (cell, index) => {
    let header = headers[index];
    let prop = header.innerText;
    let value = cell.innerText;
    obj[prop] = value;
   });
   all.push(obj);
  })
  return all;
 }
}

var arr = [
  { firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Miller' },
  { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Jester' }
];

var tbl = new HtmlTable(document.querySelector('#app'), 'teamTable', 'w3-table-all w3-hoverable w3-margin-top w3-margin-bottom', arr);
```

```html
<div id='app'></div>
```

I get an type Error when trying to call a class method in the constructor.

I call it with 'this.methodName'.

But the Browser shows Uncaught TypeError: this.createHeader is not a function

```
class HtmlTable extends HtmlElement {

    constructor(container, id, classes, arrayWithObjects){
        super(container, 'table', id, classes);

        this.arrayWithObjects = arrayWithObjects;
        this.columns = Object.keys(this.arrayWithObjects);

        if(this.columns.length > 0) this.createHeader(this.columns);   //HtmlTable.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: this.createHeader is not a function
        if(this.arrayWithObjects.length > 0 ) this.createDataRows(this.arrayWithObjects);
    }

    createHeader(columns){
        console.log(columns);
    }

    createDataRows(arrayWithObjects){
        console.log(arrayWithObjects);
    }
}

class HtmlElement {

    constructor(container, tag, id, classes, text){
        let html = document.createElement(tag);
        classes.split(' ').forEach(cls => html.classList.add(cls));
        if(text) html.innerText = text;
        html.id = id;
        container.appendChild(html);
        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `HtmlElement`? And `if(this.columns)` condition is redundant because even an empty array is *truthy*

Comment: Can you produce a self-contained example, which can even be executable right here on the site using the Snippets tool (the "`<>`" thingy in the editor toolbar…)? Including how you *instantiate* the class?

Comment: Thx for the hint, I added the executable code. Same error though. Can't figure out what to change.

Comment: The problem is that your parent constructor is `return`ing `html`, which makes `this` a `table` HTML element. You should manipulate `this` in the constructor, not return a different object.